# For which of the following conditions $ \ x ^ y \ge y^x \ $ is always true

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers

Let $x$ and $y$ be positive numbers, which of the following always implies $x^y \ge y^x$,

1. $x \le e \le y$
2. $y \le e \le x$
3. $x \le y \le e \ $ or $ \ e \le y \le x$
4. $y \le x \le e \ $ or $ \ e \le x \le y$

I just want a hint to start. I've tried a lot but can't think where to begin. Although I have an assumption that option a is correct because I've dealt with a problem where I needed to determine if $e^π \ge π^e$ is true and I went on like this :

For $ x \gt 0$,
$\ e^x \gt 1+x $.

Then, putting $x= \frac{π}{e} - 1$ in the above inequality we get,

$ \quad e^ {(\frac{π}{e} - 1)} \gt 1+ (\frac{π}{e} - 1) = \frac{π}{e}
$

This implies, $ \quad e ^ \frac{π}{e} \gt ( \frac{π}{e} ) \cdot e$

$ \quad \therefore \ e^π \gt π^e$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ has a global maximum, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner%27s_calculus_problem).

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't think of it like this... it's really easy now. I got confused with thinking y as the functional value. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint to start: Look at the function $\frac{x}{\log x}$, where is it increasing? where is it decreasing? Express the inequality $x^y\geq y^x$ in terms of this function.

Comment: The function you stated above has infinite discontinuity at $ x=1$ and it is decreasing on $ [0,1) \cup (1,e] $ and increasing on $ [e, \infty] $. So for that I guess the point $x=1$ gets excluded from the inequality as none of the points $x, \ y$ can take the value 1, which is a small fault I guess.